# Huge slowdown with string.count() when reading certain data with certain characters

Tags: python, string, performance

I need to read in a large csv data file which is however riddled with newline characters and generally quite chaotic. So instead of pandas I do it manually, however I'm running into a strange slow-down which seems to depend on the characters which appear in the file.

While trying to recreate the problem by randomly creating a csv file which looks similar I figured that maybe the problem lies in the `count` function.

Consider this example which creates a large file with chaotic random data, reads the file and then by using count orders it such that it can be read as columnar data.

Note that in the first run of the file I only use `string.ascii_letters` for the random data, for the second run I'm using characters from `string.printable`.

```
import os
import random as rd
import string
import time

# Function to create random data in a specific pattern with separator ";":
def createRandomString(num,io,fullLength):
    lineFull = ''
    nl = True
    randstr = ''.join(rd.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(7))
    for i in range(num):
        if i == 0:
            line = 'Start;'
        else:
            line = ''
            bb = rd.choice([True,True,False])
            if bb:
                line = line+'\"\";'
            else:
                if rd.random() < 0.999:
                    line = line+randstr
                else:
                    line = line+rd.randint(10,100)*randstr
                if nl and i != num-1:
                    line = line+';\n'
                    nl = False
                elif rd.random() < 0.04 and i != num-1:
                    line = line+';\n'
                    if rd.random() < 0.01:
                        add = rd.randint(1,10)*'\n'
                        line = line+add
                else:
                    line = line+';'
        lineFull = lineFull+line
    return lineFull+'\n'

# Create file with random data:
outputFolder = "C:\\DataDir\\Output\\"
numberOfCols = 38
fullLength = 10000
testLines = [createRandomString(numberOfCols,i,fullLength) for i in range(fullLength)]
with open(outputFolder+"TestFile.txt",'w') as tf:
    tf.writelines(testLines)

# Read in file:
with open(outputFolder+"TestFile.txt",'r') as ff:
    lines = []
    for line in ff.readlines():
        lines.append(unicode(line.rstrip('\n')))

# Restore columns by counting the separator:
linesT = ''
lines2 = []
time0 = time.time()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    linesT = linesT + lines[i]
    count = linesT.count(';')
    if count == numberOfCols:
        lines2.append(linesT)
        linesT = ''
    if i%1000 == 0:
        print time.time()-time0
        time0 = time.time()
print time.time()-time0
```

The print statements output this:

```
0.0
0.0019998550415
0.00100016593933
0.000999927520752
0.000999927520752
0.000999927520752
0.000999927520752
0.00100016593933
0.0019998550415
0.000999927520752
0.00100016593933
0.0019998550415
0.00100016593933
0.000999927520752
0.00200009346008
0.000999927520752
0.000999927520752
0.00200009346008
0.000999927520752
0.000999927520752
0.00200009346008
0.000999927520752
0.00100016593933
0.000999927520752
0.00200009346008
0.000999927520752
```

Consistently fast performance.

Now I change the third line in `createRandomString` to `randstr = ''.join(rd.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(7))`, my output now becomes this:

```
0.0
0.0759999752045
0.273000001907
0.519999980927
0.716000080109
0.919999837875
1.11500000954
1.25199985504
1.51200008392
1.72199988365
1.8820002079
2.07999992371
2.21499991417
2.37400007248
2.64800000191
2.81900000572
3.04500007629
3.20299983025
3.55500006676
3.6930000782
3.79499983788
4.13900017738
4.19899988174
4.58700013161
4.81799983978
4.92000007629
5.2009999752
5.40199995041
5.48399996758
5.70299983025
5.92300009727
6.01099991798
6.44200015068
6.58999991417
3.99399995804
```

Not only is the performance very slow but it is consistently becoming slower over time.

The only difference lies in the range of characters which are written into the random data.

The full set of character which appear in my real data is this:

```
charSet = [' ','"','&',"'",'(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/','0','1','2','3','4','5','6',
           '7','8','9',':',';','<','=','>','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K',
           'L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','\\','_','`','a',
           'b','d','e','g','h','i','l','m','n','o','r','s','t','x']
```

Lets do some benchmarking on the `count`-function:

```
import random as rd
rd.seed()

def Test0():
    randstr = ''.join(rd.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(10000))
    randstr.count('7')

def Test1():
    randstr = ''.join(rd.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10000))
    randstr.count('a')

def Test2():
    randstr = ''.join(rd.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(10000))
    randstr.count(';')

def Test3():
    randstr = ''.join(rd.choice(charSet) for _ in range(10000))
    randstr.count(';')
```

I'm testing only digits, only letters, printable, and the charset from my data.

Results of `%timeit`:

```
%timeit(Test0())
100 loops, best of 3: 9.27 ms per loop
%timeit(Test1())
100 loops, best of 3: 9.12 ms per loop
%timeit(Test2())
100 loops, best of 3: 9.94 ms per loop
%timeit(Test3())
100 loops, best of 3: 8.31 ms per loop
```

The performance is consistent and doesn't suggest any problems of `count` with certain character sets.

I also tested if concatenating strings with `+` would cause a slow down but this wasn't the case either.

Can anyone explain this or give me some hints?

EDIT: Using Python 2.7.12

EDIT 2: In my original data the following is happening:

The file has around 550000 lines which are often broken by random newline characters yet defined by always 38 `";"`-delimiters. Until roughtly 300000 lines the performance is fast, then from that line on it suddenly starts getting slower and slower. I'm investigating this further now with the new clues.

Comment: Use a tally instead of the `count()` method. That way performance is linear, not quadratic.

Comment: `fullLength` and `time` undefined when I try to run your code. Please adjust your example code slightly. I defined one and imported one.

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Can you please elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: @Mai: Sorry, I adjusted my code, it should run now.

Comment: @Sebastian Wozny: 2.7.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `count(';')`.

`string.printable` contains `';'` while `string.ascii_characters` doesn't.

Then as the length of `linesT` grows, the execution time grows as well:

```
0.000236988067627
0.0460968017578
0.145275115967
0.271568059921
0.435608148575
0.575787067413
0.750104904175
0.899538993835
1.08505797386
1.24447107315
1.34459710121
1.45430088043
1.63317894936
1.90502595901
1.92841100693
2.07722711563
2.16924905777
2.30753016472
```

[image: Faulty runtime behaviour]
In particular this code is problematic with `string.printable`:

```
 numberOfCols = 38
 if count == numberOfCols:
        lines2.append(linesT)
        linesT = ''
```

Since there is a chance that  `';'` is included more than once in line 37 just before `linesT` is flushed, `38` will be skipped and `linesT` grows indefinitely.

You can observe this behaviour by leaving the initial set to `string.ascii_characters` and changing your code to `count('a')`.

To fix the problem with printable you can modify your code like this:

```
if count > numberOfCols:
```

Then we go back to the expected runtime behaviour:

```
0.000234842300415
0.00233697891235
0.00247097015381
0.00217199325562
0.00262403488159
0.00262403488159
0.0023078918457
0.0024049282074
0.00231409072876
0.00233006477356
0.00214791297913
0.0028760433197
0.00241804122925
0.00250506401062
0.00254893302917
0.00266218185425
0.00236296653748
0.00201988220215
0.00245118141174
0.00206398963928
0.00219988822937
0.00230193138123
0.00205302238464
0.00230097770691
0.00248003005981
0.00204801559448
```

Comment: You are right-.-. I found something different that I can't explain.

Comment: Now that is an interesting find. I added `randstr = randstr.replace(';',':')` into my function and the performance jumped up high. I don't understand how this would lead to a slowdown since all I do is count every `";"` until I have 38 and then append that string to a list. Why does having some more random `";"` in the data make such a giant difference? Wouldn't that just mean having more lines in the end? Also if you take a look at the charset of my original data then you can see that there is no `";"` in there since it's the csv delimiter.

Comment: Check out my answer. Eventually you have 2 `';'` in your 37th line and count==38 fails. You add semicolons in this line              `      line = line+';\n'` and `                    line = line+';'` and more

Comment: You are on the right track, I'm testing my original data and after some point `linesT` doesn't get flushed anymore and piles up.

Comment: @Sebastian Wozny: Changing from `==` to `>=` solved the problem. It's really strange that this even happens though, since after exactly 38 occurrences of `';'` one row of the csv is done and a new line should always start, without exception since this data is being used by other people and in other circumstances as well. Very strange, thank you for solving this.

Answer (score 1):

I am just reporting what I found. The performance difference seemingly does not come from `str.count()` function. I changed your code and refactored the `str.count()` into its own function. I also put your global code into a main function. The following is my version of your code:

```
import os
import time
import random as rd
import string
import timeit

# Function to create random data in a specific pattern with separator ";":
def createRandomString(num,io,fullLength):
    lineFull = ''
    nl = True
    randstr = ''.join(rd.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(7))
    #randstr = ''.join(rd.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(7))
    for i in range(num):
        if i == 0:
            line = 'Start;'
        else:
            line = ''
            bb = rd.choice([True,True,False])
            if bb:
                line = line+'\"\";'
            else:
                if rd.random() < 0.999:
                    line = line+randstr
                else:
                    line = line+rd.randint(10,100)*randstr
                if nl and i != num-1:
                    line = line+';\n'
                    nl = False
                elif rd.random() < 0.04 and i != num-1:
                    line = line+';\n'
                    if rd.random() < 0.01:
                        add = rd.randint(1,10)*'\n'
                        line = line+add
                else:
                    line = line+';'
        lineFull = lineFull+line
    return lineFull+'\n'


def counting_func(lines_iter):
    try:
        return lines_iter.next().count(';')
    except StopIteration:
        return -1


def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


# Create file with random data:
def main():
    fullLength = 100000
    outputFolder = ""
    numberOfCols = 38
    testLines = [createRandomString(numberOfCols,i,fullLength) for i in range(fullLength)]
    with open(outputFolder+"TestFile.txt",'w') as tf:
        tf.writelines(testLines)

    # Read in file:
    with open(outputFolder+"TestFile.txt",'r') as ff:
        lines = []
        for line in ff.readlines():
            lines.append(unicode(line.rstrip('\n')))

    # Restore columns by counting the separator:
    lines_iter = iter(lines)
    print timeit.timeit(wrapper(counting_func, lines_iter), number=fullLength)


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Tests are done 100000 times on each line generated. With `string.ascii_letters`, I get from timeit on average `0.0454177856445` seconds each loop. With `string.printable`, I get on average `0.0426299571991`. In fact the latter is slightly faster than the former, though not really a significant difference.

I suspect the performance difference comes from what you are doing in the following loop besides counting:

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    linesT = linesT + lines[i]
    count = linesT.count(';')
    if count == numberOfCols:
        lines2.append(linesT)
        linesT = ''
    if i%1000 == 0:
        print time.time()-time0
        time0 = time.time()
```

Another possibility is slow-down from accessing global variable without a main function. But that should happen in both case, so not really.